# centralized logging with flex

Tags: apache-flex, logging, flash-builder

we're developing an application and we need for this and further projects a centralized logging. I know there is a build in log api in flex builder 4.5. And the loger has a log target. All i found is how to send these loginformations to the trace console.
But i'm looking for sending the logfiles to my server.

Maybe i can send messages to a webservice which fill a database in the backend. I dont'know if this is a recommanded way.

How do you store your log informations centralized?

Thanks in advance
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an out of the box way to do this as far as I know.

I have a log class that has a connection to the server through a remote object.  This could also be a web service.

I use a singleton pattern for that log class.

I use it to log errors in an AIR app.  I have a global error handler to catch unhandled exceptions.  I then call a log class that just calls a remote object and records the error to a log table.

The log class is flexible enough to handle debug and info statements.  I pretty much copy the log4net way to log errors which allows me to specify a type (debug, error, info, ect) and a message.  You could overload the method so you can send it more information (like message, elapsed time, userID, class, ect).

Here's a function that we use to log errors:

```
public function LogApplicationError(memberID:int, logger:String, message:String, name:String, stackTrace:String, responder:IResponder = null ):void
  {
      var asyncToken:AsyncToken = remoteObject.LogApplicationError(memberID, logger, message, name, stackTrace);

      trace("Member ID   : " + memberID.toString());
      trace("Logger      : " + logger);
      trace("Message     : " + message);
      trace("Name        : " + name);
      trace("Stack Trace : " + stackTrace);

      if( responder != null )
          asyncToken.addResponder( responder );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Log4Fx offers some flexible logging solution on top of Flex logging with a couple of out-of-the-box server logging solutions. You can read more details [here](http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2007/11/13/boost-productivity-of-your-flex-java-project-with-log4fx-component). Log4Fx is a part of free and open source [Clear Toolkit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cleartoolkit/).

Comment: Do you have some experience with log4fx. I read the stuff before and i understand, logging is only possible, if you connect with your console. What i need is a permanent logging, so a piece on the webserver should receive messages and store it to a place (db or file). Do you know, if this is possible with log4fx?

Comment: I'm one of the authors of client side code of Log4Fx :) You can adjust server code to do what you want (it includes `Socket` log target to log to servlet which can be customized). To switch logging off you can comment logging tags. The only problem is if you're using Flex 4. It seems Log4Fx does not support it.

Comment: wow, so you have the knowledge. Really, log4fx does not support flex4? I'm using flex4.5 and i assume, this is also not supported. What a pity, so this is not a solution.

Comment: This solution was developed in 2006 and not switched to Flex 4. As far as project is open sourced you can help with it if you're interested in :)